# Running CPython functions from C#

Tags: c#, .net, python

I'm working on a project where I need to be able to run a python function that depends on SciPy/NumPy.  Due to this being an add-on to a project already in progress, using IronPython would not be an option.

Additional info:

- **Python.NET** seemed to be a good fit, but I was unable to get the return value from *RunString()* (it would only return NULL).
- Passing arguments and catching the return value (a tuple) is necessary.
- The function is in a statistical package that was created by a support group for the team, so modification of that would also not be possible.

I'm at quite a loss for what to do. Any hints in the right direction are appreciated. Thanks for any help you can give!

I understand that this may be quite vague, but I cannot give explicit details to the project. If any clarification is needed please let me know and I'll do my best!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could write a DLL that uses the CPython API to expose the function, then call it in C#?
It's possible to embed the Python interpreter; although I've never done this personally, I guess it would be useful: http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html

Comment: Thank you! I'll investigate this.

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be portable beyond Windows? If not, perhaps you can embed the CPython interpreter with C++/CLI, wrap that in a nice .Net-ish interface and use the resulting code from C#. Never tried that, so I don't know if it's going to work.

Regardless if you go through this route or the 'write a native DLL' route, it will probably be easier to to embed python using [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/python/doc/), though I'm not sure if your wrapper code enough is going to be large enough to make all of this (compiling the Boost behemoth, learning Boost.Python, making sure it works with C++/CLR, increasing your target file size) worth it.

Answer (score 1):

[IronPython using DLR](http://krishnabhargav.blogspot.com/2009/02/make-your-net-application-extendible.html) might be the way to go.  Mind you it won't be the fastest way, but it seems like something worth pursuing if you're going to do this a lot.  [Another useful link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2009/10/25/hosting-ironpython-in-a-c-4-0-program.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! I'll read up a bit and see if this would work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The [ironclad](http://code.google.com/p/ironclad/) project was started to allow using CPython extensions from IronPython, especially SciPy/NumPy it seems. I don't know how usable it is (and how actively it is still being developed)